# Git: How do I list only local branches?

Tags: git, git-branch

`git branch -a` shows both remote and local branches.

`git branch -r` shows remote branches.

Is there a way to list just the local branches?

Answer (score 1640, accepted):

Just `git branch` without options.

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/git-branch.1.html):

> With no arguments, existing branches are listed and the current branch will be highlighted with an asterisk.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to list local branches that have no corresponding remote branch.

Comment: Not completely but answers to my question [How do I list local branches that have no remote branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144602/git-how-do-i-list-local-branches-that-have-no-remote-branch) provide some help.

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter I love how you found a way to get a bunch of points anyway! So funny.

Comment: @SteveCrane here's how you list local branches without a remote branch with the same name in origin: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41638933/585725

Comment: how is this the right answer to what was asked ("... to list ***just the local** branches...")???

Comment: @wdanda It does list only local branches. If you are looking for an answer to something like "How do I list branches that do not exist in any remote?" that's something totally different with Git.

Comment: @gertvdijk @wdanda - but that what my english skills tells me it's what he asking
`Git: How do I list only local branches?` = that is list *only* the local branches, why would he put *only* if he wanted "How do I list local branches". Semantics - the `only local branch` is imho the branch which is *only local* - not *local and remote*

Comment: @gr4viton But it lists only local branches. If you set up a local branch to track a remote branch, it's still a local branch. What other definition of a local branch do you have? Do you want to exclude branches created locally that also exist on any of the remotes? And what if they are named differently on a remote? It's still a very vague definition of local imo. It can be different for anyone as well.

Comment: @gr4viton: In the dialects of English that I'm familiar with, "list only local branches" usually parses as "list only those branches that are local". (To say "list those branches that are only local", I would say "list local-only branches".)

Answer (score 250):

Just the plain command

```
git branch
```

Answer (score 127):

`git branch -a` - **All** branches.

`git branch -r` - **Remote** branches only.

`git branch` - **Local** branches (contains local branches linked to a remote branch).

Answer (score 47):

One of the most straightforward ways to do it is

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/
```

This works perfectly for scripts as well.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for `git branch` tends to list things that are not local branches ... like `HEAD`.

Comment: Thanks for showing the scripting-friendly way to do it!

Answer (score 36):

If the leading asterisk is a problem, I pipe the `git branch` as follows

```
git branch | awk -F ' +' '! /\(no branch\)/ {print $2}'
```

This also eliminates the '(no branch)' line that shows up when you have detached head.

Comment: Had to modify this to `git branch | awk  -F ' +' '$2 !~ /detached/ {print $2}'` for git version 1.9.1.

Comment: `cut -c 3-` is an easier option

Answer (score 19):

Here's how to list local branches that do not have a remote branch in origin with the same name:

```sh
git branch | sed 's|* |  |' | sort > local
git branch -r | sed 's|origin/||' | sort > remote
comm -23 local remote
```

Comment: Nice, also oneliner:  
``comm -23 <(git branch | sed 's|* |  |' | sort) <(git branch -r | sed 's|origin/||' | sort )``

Answer (score 14):

Other way for get a list just local branch is:

```
git branch -a | grep -v 'remotes'
```

Answer (score 8):

There's [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31776247/3461729) to a post about how to delete local-only branches. In it, the following builds a command to list out the local branches:

```
git branch -vv | cut -c 3- | awk '$3 !~/\[/ { print $1 }'
```

The answer has a great explanation about how this command was derived, so I would suggest you go and read that post.

Comment: Thank you for linking the answer. I needed an algo to list local branches that **DO NOT** track a remote. This one is the only one that does the job.

Answer (score 5):

To complement [gertvdijk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370714/git-how-do-i-list-only-local-branches/12370765#12370765) - I'm adding few screenshots in case it helps someone quick.

In my [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) shell if I run below command:

```
git branch
```

This command (without parameters) shows all my local branches. The current branch which is currently checked out is shown in *different* color (green) along with an asterisk (*) prefix which is really intuitive.

[image]

When you try to see all branches including the remote branches using `-a`(stands for *all*) parameter:

```
git branch -a
```

Then remote branches which aren't checked out yet are also shown in *different* (red) color:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `git branch`'s `--format`, you can show local branches and their configured `remote` and `merge` configuration (as found in the repo's `.git/config` file).

```
git branch --format='%(HEAD) %(refname:short) -> %(upstream:short)'
```

See the [format doc for `git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) which is used by [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)

You can add it as an alias in your `~/.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
        [...]
        brem = branch --format='%(HEAD) %(refname:short) -> %(upstream:short)'
        [...]
```

## Example

- There are 5 local branches
- There are 2 remote locations: `origin` and `upstream`
- Local branch named `upstream` is configured to push/pull to the `upstream`'s `main` branch
- Local branch named `test` has not been pushed anywhere and does not have a remote / merge configured

```
> git branch --format='%(HEAD) %(refname:short) -> %(upstream:short)'
* main -> origin/main
  release/v0.01 -> origin/release/v0.01
  release/v0.02 -> origin/release/v0.02
  test ->
  upstream -> upstream/main
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```sh
git show-ref --heads
```

The [answer by gertvdijk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370714/git-how-do-i-list-only-local-branches/12370765#12370765) is the most concise and elegant, but this may help grasp the idea that `refs/heads/*` are *equivalent* to local branches.

Most of the time the `refs/heads/master` ref is a file at `.git/refs/heads/master` that contains a Git commit hash that points to the Git object that represents the current state of your local master branch, so each file under `.git/refs/heads/*` represents a local branch.

Answer (score 0):

[PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) users can use its [Compare-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) cmdlet to do something like this:

```
function match-branch {
    $localBranches = ((git branch -l) -replace "\*", "") -replace " ", ""
    $remoteBranches = (((git branch -r) -replace "\*", "") -replace " ", "") -replace "origin/", ""
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $localBranches -DifferenceObject $remoteBranches -IncludeEqual
    | Select-Object @{Label = "branch"; Expression = { $_.InputObject } },
    @{Label = ”both”; Expression = { $_.SideIndicator -eq "==" } },
    @{Label = ”remoteOnly”; Expression = { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" } },
    @{Label = ”localOnly”; Expression = { $_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" } }
}
```

#### Example Output

```
branch        both remoteOnly localOnly
------        ---- ---------- ---------
master        True      False     False
HEAD->master False       True     False
renamed      False       True     False
```

Answer (score 0):

List all local branches that might have remote
`git branch`

To list local branches with changes that not merged to remote yet
`git branch --list --no-merged`

To list local that never was linked to remote
`git branch -vv | awk '/: gone]/{print $1}'`