# Git: How do I list local branches that are tracking remote branches that no longer exist?

Tags: git

How can I list any local branches that appear (as per `.git/config`) to be tracking remote branches that no longer exist? Remote branches are on GitHub in this case but I suspect their location has no relevance.

For example:

1. I have local branches, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.
2. `a` is tracking `origin/a` and `c` is tracking `origin/c`.
3. `b` and `d` are not tracking remote branches.
4. `origin/a` has been been merged back into master and was deleted during a repository clean-up; I no longer need to keep local branch `a`.
5. If local branch `a` is checked out to the working tree, running `git fetch` or `git pull` results in the error `Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'a' from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.`

How would I produce the list containing only `a` and any other local branches that appear to be tracking remote branches that no longer exist?

I would like to identify these so that I can delete obsolete local branches I no longer need.

The list should not include local branches `b` or `d` that are not tracking remote branches, and also not `c` that is tracking `origin/c`, which still exists.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661853/list-all-local-branches-without-a-remote

Comment: You need to check the `.git/config` file for what branches have upstreams configured, and which they are. Assuming that a local branch has an upstream with an identical name is going to get you into trouble.

Comment: I've revised your question based on your update, please review it and roll it back if the revision is still incorrect with what you're asking

Comment: @STW your revision doesn't really convey what I was asking. I will revise the question again.

Comment: @SteveCrane cool, your edits look good.  I'm pretty sure my revised answer below is what you need

Comment: Is there a solution to this? None of the answers are marked as accepted and I'm curious as well.

Comment: I know it's an old post but the jthill solution gave me a result much easier to parse than git branch -vv which is broken as soon as your description contains "[]" characters ...

Comment: After some testing. I believe the answer by Anton Styagun is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
LANG=en git branch --format='%(if:equals=gone)%(upstream:track,nobracket)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)' | grep '.'
```

Comment: This is definitely the answer to OPs question, it should be accepted.

Comment: This seems to work very well when it is run after the `git remote prune origin` command, thank you! 
I used `xargs` to feed this into `git branch -D` to delete those branches as well.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 I use it within a `git branch-purge` command. To make such a `git` command available create a `git-branch-puge` executable in your path like this: https://github.com/astyagun/.files/blob/268503c172f384279f11ac12a55634832cb54f72/bin/git-branch-purge.

Comment: @AntonStyagun Your github gist is missing.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 I've made the repo public, try again

Comment: @AntonStyagun I thought this is something you add to the gitconfig alias or you add this to the .bashrc. Thanks though, I'm assuming you add this to the `/usr/local/bin` on Ubuntu.

Comment: The answer is not fully cross platform (i.e. can't cut & paste the full answer and run in Powershell) but when isolated the `git branch` command in it does provide the answer to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

If your local branches are tracking the remote branch you can filter the list of branches so show the ones that do not have a tracking branch with:

```
git branch -vv | grep -v origin
```

This will provide some extra information about the last commit that is on the branch but you can filter that out

```
git branch -vv | grep -v origin | awk '{print $1}'
```

This will only print the name of the branch that isn't tracking a remote branch.

Answer (score 7):

To list your local branches which track deleted remote branches you can use `git remote prune --dry-run`

For example (assuming your remote repository is named `origin`):

```
git fetch
git remote prune origin --dry-run
```

You can remove the `--dry-run` option to delete the branches from your local repository

Comment: Reading up on this, it sounds like just what I needed but after trying it, I'm not sure it is.

Comment: if your question has fundamentally changed, but this answers this particular question, then you can always ask another question ;)

Comment: No, the question is the same. I ran out of time to clarify yesterday and will do so now.

Comment: Reading up on this, it sounded like just what I needed but after trying it, I'm not sure it was.

`git branch --list` results include `a`, then I ran `git remote prune origin` which said `* [pruned] origin/a`. Now `git branch --list` results still include `a`, `git checkout a` reported that the upstream was gone and suggested `git branch --unset-upstream`. I did that and can see in `.git/config` it is no longer tracking but the local branch remains and I must delete it myself. The result I hoped for was for the local branch to be deleted. This answer gets me part of the way there.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. For example, when I run the command my output is empty, but I have many local branches that meet the question's criteria.

Answer (score 6):

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --format='%(refname:short) %(upstream)' \
| awk 'NF==1'
```

will do it. `NF` is awk's "number of fields", and its default action is print.