# read only remote git branches that are existing

Tags: git

i need to read all remote branches that are still existing.

currently i used and test the following two commands:

1. git branch -r --no-merged
2. git for-each-ref --merged HEAD --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)" refs/remotes/origin

Both give me a list of remote branches but in this list are also branches that are already deleted.

I found here in the forum one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144602/git-how-do-i-list-local-branches-that-are-tracking-remote-branches-that-no-long) like my but the answer used grep and i'm on a system were i cannot used it.

Comment: By default, doing a fetch will only bring in/update branches which actually exist on the remote.  What is your end goal here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your Git *delete*, from your Git repository, any remote-tracking name (such as `origin/feature/tall`) that no longer has a corresponding *branch* name in the other Git repository over at `origin`.

Remember that the way `git clone` works is:

- copy all the *commits* from the other Git repository, but none of the *branch names;*
- have the other Git list out its branch names;
- create, in your own repository, a *remote-tracking name* for each *branch* name that they have;
- and finally, create one local branch name for your own use.

Subsequent `git fetch` operations, including those run by `git pull`, contact the other Git and read any branch names from the other Git repository, and use those to create or update your own Git repository's remote-tracking names.  So if they *add* a `feature/short`, you get an `origin/feature/short`.  But your Git does not *delete* your existing `origin/feature/tall` merely because they've deleted their `feature/tall`, by default.  So after some time, you accumulate remote-tracking names for branch names that no longer exist.

To *delete* these, you must *tell your own Git to do that*.  There are a number of ways to do this:

- You can run `git fetch --prune`.  This has your Git ask their Git (their repository) about their branch names, and then removes from your repository any remote-tracking names that correspond to branch names that don't exist there now.  Note that this does not affect any of your *branch* names.  It only causes your own Git to remove stale *remote-tracking* names.
- You can run `git remote prune origin`.  This is like `git fetch --prune` except that it doesn't add or update remote-tracking names based on updated or new branch names on the remote, i.e., it does only the pruning step.
- You can set `fetch.prune` to `true` in your Git configuration.  If you do this, all `git fetch` operations *default* to pruning.

I use the last of these myself.  I think it should be the default, in Git, but it's not.