# Is there a way on Git to retrieve a branch whos name I forgot? One that hasnt been pushed to or upstream set

Tags: git, github, branch, bitbucket

Earlier today, I created a branch with a rather long, kebab-cased name and have come back to my computer later to realize maybe it was too long, as I dont really remember the exact order for the array of words chosen.

I dont see the branch as available on bitbucket because (i assume) it hasnt been pushed to and/or the upstream has not been set on it.

How can I retrieve it? is there any way to see a log of branch checkout activity?

I had already closed the terminal window wherein I cut the branch originally, so i cant find it by pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> thru terminal history.

if i knew some keywords of the branch, is it possible run

```
git grep
```

with some kind of parameters to find it?

Comment: gir branch shows all your branches isn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: How do I list only local branches?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370714/git-how-do-i-list-only-local-branches)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list all branches with

`git branch -a`

So maybe

`git branch -a | grep keyword` will help

Answer (score 0):

use

### git branch

it shows all local branch names.

Answer (score 0):

Using '**git branch**' will list all your local branches.
That probably will help you to remember the name of the branch you forgot.