# Show custom form then trigger a job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to show a dynamically generated form (for example with a list of currently existing branches) then trigger a job with the selected parameters.

There is [Pipeline Input Step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) but:

> You can optionally request information back, hence the name of the step. The parameter entry screen can be accessed via a link at the bottom of the build console log or via link in the sidebar for a build.

I need after clicking "Build" to show the custom form immediately.

A solution I see is to have a third party web-server which generates the form then remotely triggers the job, but I would rather use something available inside Jenkins, so that I would have access to Jenkins internals when rendering the form template (using Groovy).

Is there a solution?

Comment: I'm intrigued. Tell me if I understood well  : (01) When you click in option "build" of your job, a custom form will be rendered ? (02) Why @s-spieker answer is not correct? (03) What are the rules to generate your custom form ? Maybe a predefined input parameters could be enough.

Comment: @JRichardsz I think I found my answer -- I accepted it. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Have you tried the git Parameter Plugin ??**
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin 
The final result will populate the list of branches from your repo and you can select the branch you would like to build
[image]

**Configuration**

[image]

It's straight forward and it will build the branch that you have selected :)
This will build only 1 branch i.e. no multiple option

IF you want to do the multiple option then it gets tricky....

**You have to get the Active Choices Plug-in**
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin
[image]

Create a shell script(provide permissions)-- `get_git_branches.sh` 
add the following in the shell

```
#!/bin/bash
GIT_URL=$1
git ls-remote --heads --tags ${GIT_URL} | awk -F" " '{print $NF}'
```

**Configuration**

Add the following

```
tags = []
text = "get_git_branches.sh https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/project/repo_name.git".execute().text
text.eachLine { tags.push(it) }
return tags
```

[image]

**Pipeline**

```
node {
    echo States
    def values = Branches.split(',')
    
    for(value in values)
    println value //build them 'mvn build value'
}
```

I have given the example based on your "e.g. requirement" but if you wish to do something different like you mentioned creating a form **Active choice plugin** is the best bet as you can create your custom script with choice,textbox,multiple select (basically do a javascript page rendering) the wiki which I have posted above has great examples.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes, Active choice plugin is the thing. Somehow I missed it. Maybe I was confused by its description: "The Active Choices plugin allows the creation of dynamic and interactive parameters for freestyle Jenkins jobs". I though if it's for freestyle jobs, it doesn't work with pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own `Jenkinsfile` in groovy syntax and generate your parameters for the build. You can even create your own HTML files with that. It is part of the [Pipeline Multibranch Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin)

You can get a view like this:

[image: build with parameter]

With following `Jenkinsfile`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def buildInfo
def gitEnv

pipeline {
  agent any

  options {
    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
  }

  tools {
    nodejs 'NodeJS LTS 8.9.4'
  }
  parameters {
    choice(
        choices: 'BUILD_AND_DEPLOY\nBUILD\nDEPLOY_ONLY',
        description: '''
            Sets the desired build and deployment level
            <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Effect</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>BUILD_AND_DEPLOY</td>
                <td>BUILD and DEPLOY afterwards</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>BUILD</td>
                <td>Builds the project and uploads the resulting artifact(s)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>DEPLOY_ONLY</td>
                <td>Fetches the latest service artifact and deploys it. Replaces existing service on the agent if present.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        ''',
        name: 'deploymentLevel'
    )
  }
  stages {
    stage ('Preparation') {
        steps {
            script {
                // maybe do something special with a tag
                gitEnv = checkout scm
            }
        }
    }

    stage ('Install Dependencies') {
        when {
            anyOf {
                expression { return params.deploymentLevel == 'BUILD' }
                expression { return params.deploymentLevel == 'BUILD_AND_DEPLOY' }
            }
        }
        steps {
          bat 'npm install'
        }
    }
    stage ('and more ...')
    {
       // build and ...
    }
}
```

There is also a nice tutorial how to generate the choices from a json: [Jenkins dynamic parameters using Extended Choice Parameter Plugin and Groovy](https://medium.com/@rijoalvi/jenkins-dynamic-parameters-using-extended-choice-parameter-plugin-and-groovy-1a6ffc41063f)

Comment: I think Active choice plugin does what I need simpler. But I explore your solution too. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know ,there is no direct solution for this . What you can try (if it is extremely required ) is you can break this step into two jobs :

- A
- B

In job A you can hit build and then send a confirmation mail or slack with a form and you can fill the variables from the build . Then in that mail you have to give a url on submit which also passes the required parameters  as a GET or POST request . 
This url will point to a server side script where with the help of these parameters you can build the job B .If you decide to go with this and get stuck somewhere I can further elaborate .

Comment: This solution is not much different from having an input step, because it requires you to fill the form looking somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I see in [JENKINS-46971](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46971) there is a choice parameter:

```
def environmentChoices = ['blue', 'green'].join('\n') 
def stagingEnvironmentInpit = input( message: "apistaging.evolution-software.com is currently pointed to ${currentEnvironment}. Where do you want to promote to?", ok: 'Deploy', parameters: [choice(choices: environmentChoices, name: 'RELEASE_ENVIRONMENT')] ) 
 echo env.RELEASE_ENVIRONMENT
```

You could adapt that to your case, defining a branches variable with the [list of Git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40122019/6309):

```
def branches = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/")
```

And use that in your input step.

Comment: `input` shows a form, but only if you go to the corresponding page, find the link on the right side. > The parameter entry screen can be accessed via a link at the bottom of the build console log or via link in the sidebar for a build. < This is tedious. I want the form to be shown immediately.

Comment: @warvariuc Agreed. After testing, this does not seem a good option.

Comment: The other problem I see with this, that the build is stuck until you input the parameters... (For example someone forgets about the form).

Comment: @warvariuc In't that the goal though: to have a form shown immediately, in order for the user to input a choice?

Comment: Yes, that's the goal. My comment was related to the `input` step.